# Problema en consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Buen día

Estoy haciendo una consulta para saber el número de surcos que se encuentran sembrados actualmente y los surcos que ya fueron sembrados pero terminó la cosecha y por ende se eliminan las plantas sobrantes para una nueva siembra por granja.

Cuando hay un surco sembrado en la base de datos debe estar en `status = 1` y `type = 'SW'` sino el `status = 2`

Cuando un surco ya se sembró y cosechó debe estar en `status = '1'` y `type = 'ER'`.

El proceso es el siguiente:

En la granja 1, bloque 1 y surco 1 se hace una siembra en la base de datos y queda así;

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id |  id_land | id_block  | id_groove | type | date_register | status |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |    1     |    1      |    1      |  SW  |  2015-06-12   |    1   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cuando ya pasó el tiempo y se cosechó, se procede a eliminar las plantas y dejar el surco vacío, al registrar la base de datos queda así:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id |  id_land | id_block  | id_groove | type | date_register | status |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |    1     |    1      |    1      |  SW  |  2015-06-12   |    2   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2  |    1     |    1      |    1      |  ER  |  2015-06-12   |    1   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

El estado de la primera siembra pasa a ser 2 y la de sin siembra a ser estado 1, ahora si se vuelve a sembrar, se registra en la base de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id |  id_land | id_block  | id_groove | type | date_register | status |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |    1     |    1      |    1      |  SW  |  2015-06-12   |    2   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2  |    1     |    1      |    1      |  ER  |  2015-06-12   |    1   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3  |    1     |    1      |    1      |  SW  |  2015-06-12   |    1   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

El estado de tipo `'ER'` queda con el mismo `status = 1` y la siembra nueva queda con `status = 1`, y finalmente si vuelve a pasar la cosecha se registra nuevamente así:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id |  id_land | id_block  | id_groove | type | date_register | status |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |    1     |    1      |    1      |  SW  |  2015-06-12   |    2   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2  |    1     |    1      |    1      |  ER  |  2015-06-12   |    1   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3  |    1     |    1      |    1      |  SW  |  2016-06-12   |    2   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4  |    1     |    1      |    1      |  ER  |  2016-06-12   |    1   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Y así el proceso sucesivamente.

Tengo la siguiente consulta para saber el número de surcos que tiene un bloque con `status = 100` y `type = 'ER'`

```
SELECT id_land, COUNT(id_groove) AS units FROM sowing
WHERE type= "ER"
AND status = 100
GROUP BY id_land;
```

En esta consulta trae todos los registros tipo `'ER'` total, pero yo sólo quiero el número de surcos que se encuentren en ese estado actualmente. Por fecha no se puede por tener el mismo registro, entonces pensé que una mejor manera sería por el MAX(id) y con eso puedo obtener la cantidad de surcos, pero no se como hacerlo.

[En este SQLFiddle tengo una tabla con más datos](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac3d80/7)

Les agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Y que tiene que ver con PHP? Cambia el titulo a una pregunta especifica...

Comment: ¿de dónde sale o qué significa el status 100, no lo mencionas para nada en la pregunta?

Comment: Lo siento  estado 100 es igual a 1 y estado 200 es igual a 2

Comment: gracias por la observación @aldanux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por pasos:

Tu lo que necesitas saber, primero, es el estado actual de cada surco, dado que la fecha en tu ejemplo siempre es la misma, no parece que podamos basarnos en la fecha, así que haré la suposición que el ID va incrementando en el tiempo y utilizaremos esa información para determinar cual es el último registro ingresado para cada uno, así:

```
select id_land, id_block, id_groove, max(id)
  from sowing
 group by id_land, id_block, id_groove
```

Ahora que sabemos cual es el último registro (digamos el registro vigente) de cada uno, podemos determinar su estado haciendo un join de vuelta a la tabla original:

```
select s.*
  from (select id_land, id_block, id_groove, max(id) MaxID
          from sowing
         group by id_land, id_block, id_groove
       ) ur
       inner join sowing s on s.id_land = ur.id_land 
                          and s.id_block = ur.id_block
                          and s.id_groove = ur.id_groove
                          and s.id = ur.MaxID
```

Ahora que sabemos el estado actual de cada surco, obtener el número de los que están sembrados es trivial:

```
select count(1)
  from (select s.*
          from (select id_land, id_block, id_groove, max(id) MaxID
                  from sowing
                 group by id_land, id_block, id_groove
               ) ur
               inner join sowing s on s.id_land = ur.id_land 
                                  and s.id_block = ur.id_block
                                  and s.id_groove = ur.id_groove
                                  and s.id = ur.MaxID
       ) EstadoActual
 where type = 'SW'
```

No incluyo el status en mi *query*, pues parece que siempre que la siembra termina se inserta un registro nuevo, con lo cual el status es redundante e irrelevante, al menos para este caso.